# Literate Python

Tags: python, markdown

I liked the idea of [Literate CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#literate) and wanted to see if I could get something working with Python. I tried to accomplish something similar to this simple [Literate Ruby](https://gist.github.com/hecticjeff/5034580) and ended up with the following. The program takes Literate Python in standard input, a file, or list of files and executes just the code.

```
import fileinput
import re

code = ''

for line in fileinput.input():
    match = re.match(r'([ ]{4}|\t)(.*)', line)
    if match:
        code += match.group(2) + '\n'

exec code
```

A simple Literate Python file.

```
# Python Hello World Program

A simple example of a Literate Python Hello Word program.

    print "hello world"
```

I'm new to Python and wanted to know if I'm missing something or if there is a better solution.

Comment: `exec` like `eval` are evil!

Comment: @zmo This is actually a completely legitimate use case for `exec`.

Comment: This question really belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as it's working code and you are asking about general improvements.

Comment: Have you seen iPython notebook?  Check out this great example from Peter Norvig: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb

Comment: @Lattyware there is no legitimate use case for `exec`, as there are always better and safer alternatives… At least I have seen none so far. This use case is better dealt with the code module, as I'm showing in my example.

Comment: @zmo 'safer' - the whole point of this is to execute arbitrary code - by definition it doesn't want to be safe. Yes, the `code` module is a nicer way of doing it, it doesn't make `exec` evil in this case. Hell, [the `code` module is just calling `exec` internally](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/219502cf57eb/Lib/code.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in a comment, `eval` or `exec` are evil, a better alternative is to use the [code](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/code.html) module as in the following example. Also, you may prefer to compile the regex, in order to only perform the matching at each iteration over the input instead of building the automaton at each iteration.

```
import fileinput

import code
console = code.InteractiveConsole(locals())

import re    
r = re.compile(r'([ ]{4}|\t)(.*)')

code = ''

for line in fileinput.input():
    match = r.match(line)
    if match:
        console.push(match.group(2))
```

Though that example will output the results on `sys.stdout` so you may want to use instead an overloaded class such as the one in [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/355319-using-codeinteractiveconsole-to-embed-a-python-she/).

Comment: `code` is not inherently more or less evil then `exec` or `eval` - [it's just a wrapper around them](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/219502cf57eb/Lib/code.py). It is definitely a better way of doing this, but calling `eval`/`exec` evil here is wrong - they are only evil where you don't want to execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 2):

Combing python and markdown-like syntax is best done using tools rather than changing the language. For example:

- sphinx (render output from restructured text in doc strings or other files, both of which may have embedded code samples)
- ipython notebook (a combination of "cells" with either markdown or python code)